# The User has Cancelled The Selection on MultiImagePicker

Tags: flutter, image

I have flutter project and i want to take image from camera or gallery. for now, i use multi_image_picker: ^4.8.1 . but, after implement the code, i get error 'The User has Cancelled the selection' and pop up 'Permission denied'.

[this is error what I get on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbNvU.png)

and this is my code in camera function

```
                    child:Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(child: Text('Error: $_error')),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              loadAssets();
                            }),
                            Expanded(
                              child: buildGridView(),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

and this is my function

```
Future<void> loadAssets() async {
List<Asset> resultList = <Asset>[];
String error = 'No Error Detected';

try {
  if(await checkAndRequestCameraPermissions()) {
    resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
      maxImages: 300,
      enableCamera: true,
      selectedAssets: images,
      cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
      materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
        actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
        actionBarTitle: "Example App",
        allViewTitle: "All Photos",
        useDetailsView: false,
        selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
      ),
    );
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  error = e.toString();
}

if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {
  images = resultList;
  _error = error;
});
```

}

this is my permission function

```
Future<bool> checkAndRequestCameraPermissions() async {
// PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.camera.status;
if (await Permission.camera.request().isGranted) {
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.camera,
  ].request();
  return statuses[Permission.camera] == PermissionStatus.granted;
} else {
  return true;
}
}
```

and this is function for view image

```
Widget buildGridView() {
return GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: List.generate(images.length, (index) {
    Asset asset = images[index];
    return AssetThumb(
      asset: asset,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
    );
  }),
);}
```

this is error what i get on my Log

```
E/RecyclerView( 6058): No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xafa856c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x91312880)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xafa856c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x91312880)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa23cda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x913126f0)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglCreateContext: 0x7a964a80: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7a964a80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x913126f0)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa23cda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x913126f0)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa23cda20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x913126f0)
D/EGL_emulation( 6058): eglMakeCurrent: 0xafa856c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x91312880)
```

I'm already search. and  already use permission for camera. but, as always i get the same error. any think wrong with my code ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with permission how are you managing your permissions?

Comment: I'm already used camera permission. but, may be that permission not enough. should i used another permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the package you are using has been discontinued. I recommend using `image_pickers`.

https://pub.dev/packages/image_pickers

[image: multi_image_picker]

Comment: after i added this code. I'm still get same error with 1 new error I/art     ( 6058): JIT allocated 60KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

Comment: try using this package

Comment: ok. thank you for  the suggestion. i will try with this package